# When I concatenate a string to a pandas column, why does pandas mysteriously convert the column to a decimal?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, string-concatenation

What I wish to do is create a new column c, in dataset ab, as I was able to do in this toy example:

```
>ab=pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[5,5]],columns=['a','b'])
>ab
   a  b
0  1  2
1  5  5 
>ab=ab.assign(c=ab['b'].astype(str)+'g')
>ab 
      a  b   c
    0  1  2  2g
    1  5  5  5g
```

In my actual data, it's giving me something akin to this:

```
 >ab 
          a  b   c
        0  1  2  2.0g
        1  5  5  5.0g
```

What in the world?

The b isn't even converted to a decimal, but the newly-created variable is.

Comment: Does the happen is you try it without `assign`?: `ab['c'] = ab['b'].astype(str)+'g')`

Comment: Yes. Just tried it. Same.

Comment: Check the datatype of column b. Most likely it would be float due to some NaNs which pandas converts to float

Comment: What is the output is just `ab['b'].astype(str)`?

Comment: 00@Erfan When I do ab['b'].astype(str) I get the decimals.

`b
2.0
5.0
`

Comment: List your python and pandas version.

Comment: @Chicodelarosa Python version 3.7.4

Comment: @Chicodelarosa pandas version 0.25.1